# MySQL trigger updating field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a denormalized field which needs to mimic another field up-stream. Because of this, I'd like to create the following trigger in mysql:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
    ON UPDATE
    ON FIELD `_tracklookup`.`title_id`
    SET FIELD
        `_trackurl`.`title_id`=NEW VALUE
         WHERE `_trackurl`.`title_id`=OLD VALUE
```

Basically, I want to write a cascade statement so that the fields are always in sync. For example:

When this happens:

```
UPDATE _tracklookup SET title_id=12345 WHERE title_id=222
```

I want the following to automatically happen:

```
UPDATE _trackurl SET title_id=12345 WHERE title_id=222
```

What would be the correct trigger language for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_title_id_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON _tracklookup
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE _trackurl tu
    SET tu.title_id = NEW.title_id
    WHERE tu.title_id = OLD.title_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: missing trigger name, for each row and a ; after update statement?

Comment: @Gordon -- how do I get the "old value" and "new value" in mysql? The above doesn't work for me.

Comment: Presumably, the name of the column is not `VALUE`.  `OLD` and `NEW` are how you refer to the values in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff got it, then I'll use `NEW.title_id` and `OLD`.title_id`. Don't I need a `FOR EACH` in the above? This just gives me a general syntax error when executing in mysql.

Comment: @GordonLinoff this works -- `SET tu.title_id = 5;`, but this doesn't -- `SET tu.title_id = OLD.title_id;`. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @David542 . . . Perhaps `_tracklookup` doesn't have a column called `title_id`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I then get: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'`. My syntax is: `DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_title_id_update 
    AFTER UPDATE ON _tracklookup
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE _trackurl tu
        SET tu.title_id = NEW.title_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;`. It only works for me if I use `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: Fixed -- but I had to use the FOR EACH ROW. COuld you please add that to your answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @David542 . . . Thank you for that fix.